# How to review merge commits to detect incorrect hunks

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Normally when reviewing merge commits, we do `git diff-tree --cc <commit>` (or simply `git show <commit>`), but I'm faced with the following problem:

Say you merge `B` into `A` and during conflict resolution you need to choose a hunk from either `A` or `B` branch to resolve it. Let's say that the hunk in `A` supersedes the hunk in `B` for some reason, but since you might not know about it and judging simply by e.g. commit date, you choose hunk from `B` branch.

If you make no other modifications than that, the multi-parent diff via `git show` won't show any diff output, because the resulting hunk is in its entirety in one of the parent commits.

To further elaborate, if you have this conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
aaa
=======
bbb
>>>>>>> b
```

And remove either `aaa` hunk and choose `bbb`, or vice versa, the `git show <merge_commit>` won't show anything at all, thus preventing you to see what hunk was chosen during the merge.

This can potentially result in a regression hard to find down the line.

How could I see what hunks were chosen during a conflict resolution?

Edit: what I'm after is to view just the hunks that were conflicted (thus not auto-merged).

Comment: Doesn't `git show` show you the difference with respect to A?

Comment: from [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) and experience, shows identical output to `diff-tree --cc`, thus in respect to both `A` and `B`.

Comment: So what do you mean when yo say 'the multi-parent diff via git show won't list anything'?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: OK, now I understand - as the documentation says, `git diff-tree --cc`  'lists only files which were modified from all parents'.  As @torek says, you need to specify `-m` to suppress this behaviour and diff against all parents.

Comment: I note that the man page for `git show` doesn't explicitly describe the `-m` option, but it refers to it in the section '**combined diff format**' with the slightly ambiguous advice 'you can give the `-m` option to any of these commands to force generation of diffs with individual parents of a merge' (meaning 'with **all** parents of a merge').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: what I'm after is to view just the hunks that were conflicted (thus not auto-merged).

Not the answer you were looking for: this is not possible with `git` commands. `git` does not keep track of how a merge was resolved in any way or fashion (except for the `git rerere` cache, which does not help us here though). You would need something like a "4-way diff" (A, B, common parent and merge result), which I never heard of.

In theory, you could go back and write yourself a program that re-does the original 3-way merge to produce the intermediate file (with the conflict markers) and diff *that* to the merge result. `git` has no provisions to do that for you though.

EDIT: mentioned `git rerere`, although it does not help here.

Comment: Yea, I did have something like "re-playing the merge to figure out conflicted hunks" in mind. Thought it'd possible to do via `git` alone. Accepted as sad truth.

Answer (score 1):

Diff the merge against a particular parent (or even all parents).

Usually the parent to compare with is the first-parent, i.e., `HEAD^1` or `HEAD~1` or `HEAD^` or `HEAD~` (all mean the same thing).  To compare with the second parent, choose `HEAD^2` (there is no other short way to express the second parent: you must use the hat suffix and the number).

Replace `HEAD` with the merge commit ID if the merge is not the current (HEAD) commit.

To view diffs against *all* parents, you can simply `git show -m <commit>`, which (internally only) "splits" the merge so that instead of that commit being combined-diff-ed, it's diff-ed one parent at a time against each parent.

Hence:

```
git show -m <commit>
```

(and stop once you have seen enough, or play it through to the end if you like) or:

```
git diff <commit>^ <commit>
```

Comment: I was hoping for something that would show just the hunks that were conflicted. Otherwise this shows too much irrelevant code, particularly if you have to scan both parents. This could work if you know what you're looking for. Not very useful for common merge reviews, if the merged branches were big to begin with.

Comment: Yes, definitely not built in.  It is easy enough to re-perform the merge (do it with a temporary index and work tree and either detached HEAD or no-commit flag), except that you can't tell what merge strategy (`-s`) or extended arguments (`-X ours`, `-X rename-threshold`, `-X ignore-space-*`, etc) were applied at the time.